# writing UI content to a file on a server

Tags: textarea

I've got a pop-up textarea, where the user writes some lengthy comments. I would like to store the content of the textarea to a file on the server on "submit". What is the best way to do it and how?

THanks,

Comment: You need to supply more information: what language, what kind of server, what kind of page it's coming from, etc.. Like the basic details. This is far too ambiguous.

Comment: The front-end uses html,jquery,javascript,tapestry 4.1 in the browser. The servlet container is tomcat with java app deployed. Basically, it is a form page where on a button click a pop-up textarea comes up. The user can write a free flowing text. On "Save" button on the text area the content of the text area should be written to a file on the remote server. My questions is how easily can it be done and how

Answer (score 0):

This would be very easy to do.  The text could be just a string or stringBuffer for size and formatting, then just pass that to your java code and use file operations to write to a file.

This is some GWT code, but it's still Ajax, so it will be similar.  Get a handler for an event to capture the button submittal, then get the text in the text area.

```
textArea.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() {
        public void onChange(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
            String text = textArea.getText();
        }
    });
```

The passing off mechanism I don't know because you don't show any code, but I just created a file of filenames, line by line by reading filenamesout of a list of files with this:

```
    private void writeFilesListToFile(List<File> filesList) {       
    for(File file : filesList){
        String fileName = file.getName();
        appendToFile(fileName);
    }
}

private void appendToFile(String text){
    try {
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter<file path andfile name>));
        out.write(text);
        out.newLine();
        out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error appending file with filename: " + text);
        } 
}
```

You could do something similar, only write out the few lines you got from the textarea.  Without more to go on I can't really get more specific.

HTH,

James